# Test in grails application

Tags: grails, testing

We have a grails application, which uses two databases. 
Version of grails is 2.2.1.

In development and production enviroment application works well, but in test enviroment only one datasource/session factory instead two was created.

Why it was happend?

Comment: Can you show `DataSource.groovy`? Do you have multiple datasources defined in `test` environment as well?

Comment: Hi, dmahapatro! I can't show config now, but yep, both datasources defined in config.